# Google Search Like Widget Example

Tags: android, search, widget

I am looking for example for *Google Search like home page widget* from where user can type-in keywords to search within my app. [Youtube video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLxVQi0lRQ4#t=0m55s).

I followed the tutorial at the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html). However, it lists the available RemoteViews, and there is no EditView. In such case how can I provide a editable text-box. I want to build a widget similar to SearchManager UI, but available as widget at home-screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EditText is not available on widgets. That's why there's no EditText on the search widget. It just looks like EditText. When you click over the search widget it starts another activity with EditText.

Comment: thanks for you answer. however i see this video (at 0m55s) where they show typing on home screen. how's that achieved? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLxVQi0lRQ4#t=0m55s

Comment: I see. It never works this way for me. Search activity is always started.

Answer (score 1):

As above, EditText is not available for widgets. The video you pointed to is of a fake Android. That is not a real Android device and was made for that video only.

Answer (score 0):

[Search Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) is what you are looking for. There are two ways of implementing it, 1) Using a `SearchView` (which behaves like, and is an extension of `EditText`) and   2) using a Search Dialog. I believe, you'd need to use the 1st approach.  The linked page has a nice helpful tutorial to get your started.